# Coin Change Greedy Algorithm Test Case Overtime

Tags: dynamic, initialization, timeout

Sooo confused... I don't know why the solution could not pass the test case: "coins = [186,419,83,408] amount = 6249"
It shows “overtime”. What's the problem?

Here is the code I wrote which could not pass the test case

```
class Solution {
public:
    int dfs (vector<int>& coins, int amount, vector<int>& dp){
        if (amount == 0) return 0;
        if (amount < 0) return -1;

        if (dp[amount] != -1) return dp[amount];

        int res = INT_MAX;

        for (int coin: coins){
            if (amount - coin < 0) continue;
            int subproblem = dfs(coins, amount - coin, dp);
            if (subproblem == -1) continue;
            res = min(res, subproblem + 1);
        }
        dp[amount] = (res != INT_MAX) ? res : -1;
        return dp[amount];
    }

    int coinChange(vector<int>& coins, int amount) {
        vector<int> dp(amount + 1, -1);
        return dfs(coins, amount, dp);
    }
};
```

And here is the correct one, I Initialize the dp vector to zero and also return dp[amount] when it dp[amount] != 0 rather than -1

```
class Solution {
public:
    int dfs (vector<int>& coins, int amount, vector<int>& dp){
        if (amount == 0) return 0;
        if (amount < 0) return -1;

        if (dp[amount] != 0) return dp[amount];

        int res = INT_MAX;

        for (int coin: coins){
            if (amount - coin < 0) continue;
            int subproblem = dfs(coins, amount - coin, dp);
            if (subproblem == -1) continue;
            res = min(res, subproblem + 1);
        }
        dp[amount] = (res != INT_MAX) ? res : -1;
        return dp[amount];
    }

    int coinChange(vector<int>& coins, int amount) {
        vector<int> dp(amount + 1, 0);
        return dfs(coins, amount, dp);
    }
};
```

I want to know why when I initialize the vector to zero without changing another code the test case could pass.

Like this: dp [amount] could still be -1 when I initialize the vector to zero.

```
dp[amount] = (res != INT_MAX) ? res : -1;
```